# Can i use 3 wire for service installation

Tags: wiring

I'm supplying 200amp service to a cabin.  There is a service disconnect at the meter.  Can i use 3 wire 4/0 al to the main panel and put a grounding rod at the main panel and not bond the neutral and ground bus or do i have to use 4 wire from the disconnect to the main panel supplying the ground wire through that?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use 3 wire cable for this?

Answer (score 1):

Past the service disconnect you will need 4 wire and you will need ground rods at the cabin.